# DSE (Datastax Enterprise) Sparksql capabilities

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hive, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Does Spark SQL on the DSE platform have these features?

1. Create Hive External tables to Read from Cassandra (DSEFS) and S3
2. To be done via the C* Metastore
3. Enforce RBAC (RoleBasedAuthenticationControl) from the C* Metastore
4. Run 'Hive on Spark' on DSE environment.
5. Can 'Hive on Spark' running on a separate hdfs cluster read from DSE's C* Metastore

Comment: Under Hive you mean Spark SQL? Or pure Hive?

Comment: As per my Understanding, I don't think we have this capabilities.

Comment: @AlexOtt -  pure Hive, as Ranger can not only authorize certain users/groups but also mask the Hive data. Have not read about any masking in DSE